# the build method executes twice in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does the "build" method execute twice in each class in my flutter app?

This causes variables I use to setup the screen to have the wrong value.

For example, I want to set some parts of the screen to be visible or invisible so I use a function inside the "build:" method to set visibility based on values I retrieve from the db.

```
setVisibility() {
    final trxnProvider =
        ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider); 
    trxnProvider.clientCellPhone != "" && trxnProvider.clientCellPhone != null
        ? _hasCellNumber = true
        : _hasCellNumber = false;
    trxnProvider.clientHomePhone != "" && trxnProvider.clientHomePhone != null
        ? _hasHomeNumber = true
        : _hasHomeNumber = false;

    if (trxnProvider.mlsNumber != null && trxnProvider.mlsNumber != "") {
      _propertyMLSNbr = trxnProvider.mlsNumber;
      _hasMLSNumber = true;
    } else {
      _propertyMLSNbr = null;
      _hasMLSNumber = false;
    }
  }
```

This is where I call the function:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Get the stream of transactions created in main.dart
    final trxnProvider =
        ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider); 

    DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
    DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

    setVisibility();

    return Scaffold(
```

On the first time the execution goes through the "build:" method I get the values I am expecting.

For example, the first time I pass through the "build:" method, trxnProvider.mlsNumber has a value. The second time through the code, trxnProvider.mlsNumber is null.

How do I get these variables to hold their values?

Comment: Don't declare them in build.  Declare them in the state, and initialize them in initState.

Comment: How do I declare them in the state? I can initialize them in initState. Thanks for your help

Comment: @LostTexan You declare them as member variables in your `State` class.  You should expect that your `build` method might be called multiple times.  It should be idempotent.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for your answer. I am learning flutter so I am not sure which class is the "State" class. Is it this one, class TransactionDetailScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget or this one class _TransactionDetailScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<TransactionDetailScreen> ?  I don't have any formal training in flutter so I appreciate your help while I am learning.

Comment: Your state class is `_TransactionDetailScreenState` (as hinted at by its name).